# How to calculate total daily and monthly hours from raw timesheet data?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have table like the following in Access and I want to calculate the employee total hrs on daily and monthly basis

```
EmpID InTime    OutTime     Date
1     09:00 AM  10:00 AM    1-1-14
2     09:30 AM  09:30 AM    1-1-14
3     09:00 AM  10:00 AM    1-1-14
4     12:00 AM  05:00 AM    1-1-14
1     11:00 AM  10:00 PM    1-1-14
2     12:30 PM  09:30 PM    1-1-14
3     01:00 PM  10:00 PM    1-1-14
4     02:00 PM  05:00 PM    1-1-14
```

I am using the `DateDiff` function but still to get the final output I need I think I will have to do lot of coding/nested queries. Am I right?

Comment: What are the field (column) types in the Access database? Are the date and time values in `Text` fields, or are they in `Date/Time` fields?

Comment: InTime and OutTime both are Text(bcoz Only want to store Time  hence it is fixed length Text) and Date Column is of type Date/Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raw data in a table named [TimeDataRaw]

```
EmpID  InTime    OutTime   Date    
-----  --------  --------  --------
    1  09:00 AM  10:00 AM  1/1/2014
    2  09:30 AM  09:30 AM  1/1/2014
    3  09:00 AM  10:00 AM  1/1/2014
    4  12:00 AM  05:00 AM  1/1/2014
    1  11:00 AM  10:00 PM  1/1/2014
    2  12:30 PM  09:30 PM  1/1/2014
    3  01:00 PM  10:00 PM  1/1/2014
    4  02:00 PM  05:00 PM  1/1/2014
```

you could create a saved query in Access (also known as a "View") named [TimeDataView] like this

```sql
SELECT 
    EmpID,
    [Date],
    Year([Date]) AS DateYear,
    Month([Date]) AS DateMonth,
    Day([Date]) AS DateDay,
    InTime,
    OutTime,
    DateDiff("h", CDate([Date] & " " & InTime), CDate([Date] & " " & OutTime)) AS FullHours
FROM TimeDataRaw
```

which returns

```
EmpID  Date      DateYear  DateMonth  DateDay  InTime    OutTime   FullHours
-----  --------  --------  ---------  -------  --------  --------  ---------
    1  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  09:00 AM  10:00 AM          1
    1  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  11:00 AM  10:00 PM         11
    2  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  09:30 AM  09:30 AM          0
    2  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  12:30 PM  09:30 PM          9
    3  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  01:00 PM  10:00 PM          9
    3  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  09:00 AM  10:00 AM          1
    4  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  02:00 PM  05:00 PM          3
    4  1/1/2014      2014          1        1  12:00 AM  05:00 AM          5
```

You could then run queries against that view to SUM(FullHours) and GROUP BY DateMonth or DateYear or however you wanted to aggregate the values, for example:

```sql
SELECT EmpID, DateYear, DateMonth, SUM(FullHours) AS TotalHours
FROM TimeDataView
GROUP BY EmpID, DateYear, DateMonth
```

returning

```
EmpID  DateYear  DateMonth  TotalHours
-----  --------  ---------  ----------
    1      2014          1          12
    2      2014          1           9
    3      2014          1          10
    4      2014          1           8
```

(Note that `DateDiff("h", ...)` will only return the *full hours* between time1 and time2, so the "hours difference" between '09:00 AM' to '09:59 AM' would be zero.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but some times data will be in
`EmpID InTime    OutTime     Date
1     09:00 AM  10:00 AM    1-1-14
2     09:30 AM  09:30 AM    1-1-14
3     09:00 AM  10:00 AM    1-1-14
4     12:00 AM  05:00 AM    1-1-14
1     11:00 AM  10:00 PM    1-1-14
2     12:30 PM  09:30 PM    1-1-14
3     01:00 PM  10:00 PM    1-1-14
4     02:00 AM  05:00 PM    1-1-14`
Then it comes problem

Comment: @KeshavdasM I have updated my answer with your revised sample data. So what's the problem?